# Array format error

Tags: angularjs, arrays, json

I have an array as following

{"contractID":27112016185818,"contractName":"ddf","supplierID":5,"supplierName":"hh","productID":44,"productName":"gg","uom":"uu","quantity":6,"pricePerUOM":6,"totalPrice":36,"currency":"inr","supplyByDate":"01112016","createdDate":"27112016","loginuser":"buyer","chain_id":"supplychainintegrity","height":244432,"num_txs":1,"pendingWith":"","block_hash":"hash","block_data":"data","data_hash":"datahash","block_time":"time"}

I want to convert it into the following

```
[{"contractID":27112016185818,"contractName":"ddf","supplierID":5,"supplierName":"hh","productID":44,"productName":"gg","uom":"uu","quantity":6,"pricePerUOM":6,"totalPrice":36,"currency":"inr","supplyByDate":"01112016","createdDate":"27112016","loginuser":"buyer","chain_id":"supplychainintegrity","height":244432,"num_txs":1,"pendingWith":"","block_hash":"hash","block_data":"data","data_hash":"datahash","block_time":"time"}]
```

Its for json stringification.

```
jsonObj["row"]=currentArray;
newArray=JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
```

My newArray as follows

```
{"row":{"contractID":27112016185818,"contractName":"ddf","supplierID":5,"supplierName":"hh","productID":44,"productName":"gg","uom":"uu","quantity":6,"pricePerUOM":6,"totalPrice":36,"currency":"inr","supplyByDate":"01112016","createdDate":"27112016","loginuser":"buyer","chain_id":"supplychainintegrity","height":244432,"num_txs":1,"pendingWith":"","block_hash":"hash","block_data":"data","data_hash":"datahash","block_time":"time"}}
```

need as following

{"row":[{"contractID":27112016185818,"contractName":"ddf","supplierID":5,"supplierName":"hh","productID":44,"productName":"gg","uom":"uu","quantity":6,"pricePerUOM":6,"totalPrice":36,"currency":"inr","supplyByDate":"01112016","createdDate":"27112016","loginuser":"buyer","chain_id":"supplychainintegrity","height":244432,"num_txs":1,"pendingWith":"","block_hash":"hash","block_data":"data","data_hash":"datahash","block_time":"time"}]}

Comment: Please format your JSON so that the differences are legible.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen i didn't get you

Comment: Try [this](http://jsonlint.com/) site. It is a formidable tool to find out if your JSON is properly structured and, if not, it tells you where the inconsistency is.

Comment: I already checked it validate true

Comment: @AdarshMPallickal - He is saying your JSON is unreadable.  Format it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this,

```
 $scope.newarray = [];
 $scope.myObj = data.row;
 $scope.newarray.push($scope.myObj);
 console.log($scope.newarray);
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/olD5154yBKNM8lrg5IdV?p=preview)**